# Split string column on custom separator replacing adjacent NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I want to partition the string on the `*`, and then update the second column using the right-hand side of the `*`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    '0': {'158': 'QRE', '159': 'AAA*XCN', '160': 'JJJJ'},
    '1': {'158': 'ABC', '159': np.nan, '160': np.nan},
    '2': {'158': 931, '159': 88, '160': 0},
})


# :            0    1    2
# : 158      QRE  ABC  931
# : 159  AAA*XCN  NaN   88
# : 160     JJJJ  NaN    0

expected = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    '0': {'158': 'QRE', '159': 'AAA', '160': 'JJJJ'},
    '1': {'158': 'ABC', '159': '*XCN', '160': np.nan},
    '2': {'158': 931, '159': 88, '160': 0},
})


# :         0     1    2
# : 158   QRE   ABC  931
# : 159   AAA  *XCN   88
# : 160  JJJJ   NaN    0
```

Here's what I have so far, but I'm struggling to get to the end.

```
split = df.iloc[:, 0].str.partition('*', expand=True)
df.iloc[:, 0] = split.iloc[:, 0]
rows = df.iloc[:, 1].isnull()
```

Comment: You can probably nip the problem in the bud if you modify the `sep` parameter in `read_csv`, you're not reading it in properly I believe.

Comment: Try something like `pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=r'[*,]', engine='python')`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, I'm getting the dataframe from a library that provides it this way, unfortunately

Comment: And is this data like this only for the first column? And will there only be spillovers into the second? Or does that depend?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It is just like this -- the asterisk appears in the first column or not at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html)ed `DataFrame`, also if necessary add `*` by [`radd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.radd.html):

```
split = df.iloc[:, 0].str.split('*', expand=True).rename(columns=str)
split['1'] = split['1'].radd('*')
#same like
#split['1'] = '*' + split['1']
df.update(split)
print (df)
        0     1    2
158   QRE   ABC  931
159   AAA  *XCN   88
160  JJJJ   NaN    0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `split` and `combine_first`:

```
i = df['0'].str.split('*', expand=True)
i.columns = i.columns.astype(str)

df[['0', '1']] = i.combine_first(df[['0', '1']])
```

---

```
df
        0    1    2
158   QRE  ABC  931
159   AAA  XCN   88
160  JJJJ  NaN    0
```

Comment: Can we keep the `*` in `*XCN`?

Comment: @Hatshepsut Yeah, you can do `i['1'] = i['1'].radd('*')` before the `combine_first` step.